# Underscore _.each method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am reading the underscore source code, and looking in particular at the `_.each` method.

I have whittled it down to this, but am slightly confused how it works by passing in a function.

```
_.each = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    var i, length;
    for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
    }
  return obj;
};
```

Then in the console if I write this:

```
var sum = 0;
_.each([1,2,3], function(n){
   sum += n;
});                 

//sum === 6;
```

what I am trying to understand is what exactly happens in the `_.each` method.

`obj === [1,2,3]` and `iteratee == function(n){sum += n}`.

When you plug this into the loop, is it correct on the first run of the loop

`iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);`

equates to the following?

```
function (n){
  sum += n;
}([1,2,3][0], 0, [1,2,3])
```

How does the function get invoked? Does the loop invoke it? I don't think it does

When I play around and use the following code i get the error message below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    function (n){
      sum += n;
    }([1,2,3][i], i, [1,2,3]);
 }
 console.log(sum)

 //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is going on here?

Comment: Try to wrap the function and its parameters in parenthesis.  Like this: `(function(n){ sum += n; }([1,2,3][i], i, [1,2,3]));`.

Comment: I did that, and it works, but where in the source is it an `IIFE`?

Comment: You're passing in the function as a parameter.  `iteratee` is a function.

Comment: is `iteratee` not equal to `function (n){sum += n;}`, as it is passed in as the iteratee argument?

Comment: *"How does the function get invoked? Does the loop invoke it?"* Yes. Right here: `iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);`. I think you are overcomplicating this. `foo(...)` is a function call. All that matters is that `foo` resolves to a function value. How the function was created or passed doesn't matter.

Comment: `iteratee` *is* equal to `function (n){sum += n;}` because you are passing the function in as a parameter.  In JavaScript, functions are just variables like strings and numbers.  `iteratee(...)` is how the function is getting called.

Comment: ah ha! EUREKA. Makes sense now. thanks  @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, simply your syntax as a problem:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  (function (n){
    sum += n;
  })([1,2,3][i], i, [1,2,3]);
}
console.log(sum)
```

Which is defining a new anonymous function on each iteration and invoking it right away, which is called [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Comment: is `iteratee` not equal to `function (n){sum += n;}`, as it is passed in as the `iteratee` argument? I know about `IIFE's` and that's where my confusion comes from. I dont see where this is an `IIFE` as the function is equal to `iteratee`

Comment: It is. Except when you want to define and call a function, you need to do that in two atomic statements. The parenthesis allows the JS engine to define the anonymous function first, which is contained in these parenthesis, and then call it with the given parameters. Omitting the parenthesis is a syntax error as the engine cannot know in which order to interpret what you typed.

Comment: To answer your updated comment, the difference is that we don't assign this function in a variable name such as iteratee. We define the function, still anonymous, and call it right away. And the end of this call it is going to oblivion, ready for garbage collection: nothing else is referencing it in the code.